# unsupervised Time series anomaly detection

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, anomaly-detection

I have 3D printer that working exactly 400 second for printing element X [0-400].

The printer produce 30 signals (features like VOLT,X,Y,Z,TEMP etc') in frequency of 50HZ (every sample 0.02 ms) ,for every print I monitor this features in log with time tag (0-400) .

The features are not stationary during the activation (changed ) ,the features also depends. The features value can be change from one printing to another (not exactly ), the duration of printing can change for example coloring mission can take more time in one print than other .

I want to create automate system that will detect if there anomaly (problem) during the printing process without human check  .

I have more than 100 logs (printing logs of element of type X) that I sure the are good.

I am looking machine learning algorithm for unsupervised feature learning for time series that will give me the ability to classify if the printing is good or not, I think about LSTM or DBN (deep belief Net) but something say to me their another option that may I don't know    .

Thanks.
MAK

Comment: In your scenario are you always printing the same object?

Answer (score 0):

you need not to have a time series algoritm for anomaly detection-

First of all Identify- "WHAT IS ANOMLAY IN YOUR APPLICATION", there is no algorithm that will give u direct abnormality. they are focused on outlier detection.

1) If you can generate some data at abnormality, build a classification model.

2) Can you build a relation among variables present in data. Find a relation by NN or regression, any deviation from known relation is abnormality.

3) If outliers are abnormalities in your application. I can share some links like- https://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2018/07/anomaly-detection-anomaly-detection-by.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/datamllab/tods for anomaly detection in timeseries

Answer (score 0):

I've built a number of anomaly detectors for streaming data. Here's what I would suggest:
First, consider each of your 30 features (signals) independently, i.e., build an unsupervised anomaly detector for each feature and run them in parallel. For a given component, I would:

- create bins for the values, e.g., if $x$ is in range [0,100], maybe make 10 bins [0,10), [10, 20), .. Or for something like temp, maybe your bins are [0,70), [70, 85), [85, 95), [95, 100), [100, 140), [140, infinity). Varying the width of the bins may help with some dominating all of the data. Since you're looking for anomalies, you will want the bins to be crafted so you can have less likely bins than others. On the other hand you don't want bins that never occur and ones that always occur.
- create a multinomial (a die) with the probability of a new data feature/signal observation landing in each bin. To do this, before you see any data, instantiate the bin count to 1 for all bins and store the denominator as n (number of bins).
- given a new observation of the signal, you will compute its p-value, then increment the count of the bin it landed in and the denominator.

E.g., suppose  we have three bins, $b1, b2, b3$. We initialize

`counts = {b_1: 1, b_2: 1, b_3: 1}`
`n = 3`

This means the multinomial when starting is $p(bj) = 1/3 $ for $j = 1,2,3$.

`def p(b): return counts[b]/n`

Suppose we see new data (signal) with value $x1$ and it lands in bin $b2$. First, we compute the p-value$(b_2 = \sum_{\{j:p(b_j)<= p(b_2)\}} p(b_j) = 1$ (b/c all bins have the same probability at start). Next we'd increment the count of $b_2, n$:

`counts[b_2] += 1`

`n+=1`

Second, suppose we see a second value $x_2$ that lands in bin $b_3$. Then we'd repeat the previous paragraph, computing p_value$(b_3)$ (and you'll get 2/3), and incrementing bin `b_2`'s count and the `n`.

Finally, those signals with low p-value are the anomalies.
This has lots of advantages: your p-values are comparable across all these different signals, and across time (note that your distribution is changing in time); it is fast and easy to implement. you can alert or look back over historical data;

These papers describe this workflow or an application of it in more detail:

- https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6406752
- https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8258031
- https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8440825